# Get Double value from function with a completion handler in Swift

Tags: swift

I am pretty new to Swift and (unfortunately) not an experienced developer. It is rather more a hobby and now I am now having a challenge implementing an App using HealthKit.

I have the following function (it should return the distance for a specific workout):

```
func getDistance(healthStore: HKHealthStore, training: HKWorkout, completion: @escaping (Double)-> Void){
    var type = HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)
    
    var predicate: NSPredicate? = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: training.startDate, end: training.endDate)
    
    let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: type!, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { _, result, error in
        
        guard let result = result, let sum = result.sumQuantity() else {
            completion(0.0)
            return
        }
        
        completion(sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count()))
    
    }
    
    healthStore.execute(query)
}
```

I am now wondering how I can call this function to process the distance?
I was thinking of calling the function something similar to:

```
await distance = healthKitManager.getDistance(healthStore: healthStore, training: activities[0], completion: (Double) -> Void)
```

But this is not building respectively Xcode throws two errors:

> Cannot assign value of type '()' to type 'Double' Cannot convert value
> of type '((Double) -> Void).Type' to expected argument type '(Double)
> -> Void'

Can someone give me a hint how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Tobi

I would like to process the double value to finally construct an array of Activities, but for now -  as part of try and error - I simply would like to print returned value to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to mix async/await and completion handler code. Those are incompatible ways of expressing the same idea.

Refer to the [HKStatisticsQueryDescriptor documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkstatisticsquerydescriptor) for an example of how to use an `HKAsyncQuery`. Your code would translate to:

```swift
let distance = try await healthKitManager.getDistance(
  healthStore: healthStore,
  training: activities[0]
)
```

```swift
func getDistance(healthStore: HKHealthStore, training: HKWorkout) async throws -> Double {
  try await HKStatisticsQueryDescriptor(
    predicate: .quantitySample(
      type: .init(.distanceWalkingRunning),
      predicate: HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: training.startDate, end: training.endDate)
    ),
    options: .cumulativeSum
  ).result(for: healthStore)?
    .sumQuantity()?
    .doubleValue(for: .meter()) ?? 0
}
```

But, if you already have an `HKWorkout` instance, why are you reimplementing [`statistics`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkout/3929754-statistics) ?

```swift
let distance = activities[0]
  .statistics(for: .init(.distanceWalkingRunning))?
  .sumQuantity()?
  .doubleValue(for: .meter()) ?? 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much. That really helped. And you are right, I was by mistake attempting to reimplement statistics. Which is actually not required. Hence, I simply followed your suggestion. But had to change it slightly, so that doubleValue is for HKUnity.meter().

Comment: I figured that’s what you wanted, but didn’t want to assume. I’ll edit now.